# Distinguish between simple and multiple recursion

Tags: java, recursion

our professor asked us to `Distinguish between simple and multiple recursion`, and i'm not sure if i'm understanding it right.

From what i know, multiple recursion is when a method is called more than one time during his life cycle (e.g. Fibonacci), but what about a simple recursion? Is it when  a method is called just once ? If Yes can you make an example?

This is the prof . question
[image: Question]

Comment: I've heard of tail and non tail recursion, never heard of simple and multiple ...

Comment: it is not at all stupid, it's badly written, just try adding more info

Comment: I've never heard of it either, but apparently [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Single_recursion_and_multiple_recursion) has.  But they call it "single" and "multiple" rather than "simple" and "multiple"... actually, they do call it "simple" recursion at one point later in the article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classic example of a single-call recursion<sup>1</sup> is the factorial function:

```
f(n) = n * (n-1) * (n-2) ... * 3 * 2 * 1
```

That would be implemented as pseudo-code:

```
def factorial (int n, assert n > 0):
    if  n == 1:
        return 1
    return n * factorial (n - 1)          # one call
```

Contrast that with the naive<sup>2</sup> Fibonacci generator:

```
def fib (int n, assert n >= 0):
    if n < 2:
        return 1
    return fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)      # two calls
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Wikipedia defines these terms thus, though using `single` rather than `simple`, which makes more sense in contrast to `multiple`:

> **Single recursion and multiple recursion**
>
> Recursion that only contains a single self-reference is known as single recursion, while recursion that contains multiple self-references is known as multiple recursion.
>
> Standard examples of single recursion include list traversal, such as in a linear search, or computing the factorial function, while standard examples of multiple recursion include tree traversal, such as in a depth-first search, or computing the Fibonacci sequence.

---

<sup>2</sup> Not *really* a good use case for recursion since there's a large amount of repeated effort in each of the calls. An iterative solution is much better in this case (code's a little longer but workload is minimised):

```
def fib (int n, assert n >= 0):
    if n < 2:
        return 1
    n = n - 2

    grandparent = 1
    parent = 1
    me = grandparent + parent
    while n > 0:
        n = n - 1
        grandparent = parent
        parent = me
        me = grandparent + parent
    return me
```

Comment: So the main difference is how many times you call the function right? For example, Fibonacci call fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) which is multiple recursion, while factorial is a simple recursion?

Comment: @BioShock, based on Wikipedia, yes, that's the main difference, though I tend to call it good recursion and "recursion no sane developer would even think about attempting and if my minions ever bought it to me, I'd think very carefully when we next did their performance appraisal" :-)